# How can I match data from an object and pass it as props to another component that displays dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am storing my data in JS array. After that I am using map function to display components with specific data. Until then, everything works.
After I click component I want to display a PopUp component that display more specific data from the data.js file. How can I pass it as props and match correct data to correct component? At this moment after I click it always shows me the same text.

My data.js file:

```js
export const data = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: "Project1",
      image: require("../assets/img/Project1.PNG"),
      description: "Set number 1",
      technologies: "REACT",
      link: "github.com",
    },
    {
      name: "Project2",
      image: require("../assets/img/Project2.PNG"),
      description: "Project number 2 - description",
      technologies: "C#",
      link: "github.com",
    },
```

This is my PopUp.js that should display more specific data:

```js
function Popup({ project, description }) {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <p>Project name is: {project}</p>
      <p>Description is: {description}</p>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

And here I map my data and here is the problem.
How can I pass it?

```js
function Projects() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const togglePopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {data.projects.map((proj) => (
        <ProjectContainer background={proj.image} onClick={togglePopup}>
          {isOpen && (
            <Popup project={proj.name} description={proj.description} />
          )}
        </ProjectContainer>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

Really thanks for all of the answers!

Comment: you have single `isOpen` value, and when it is true *all* popups will open

Comment: That is beucase you should set "isOpen" at ProjectContainer level, not in Projects. When you set isOpen to true, you set it for all projects at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index instead of boolean :

```
function Projects() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState('nothing');

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {data.projects.map((proj, index) => (
        <ProjectContainer background={proj.image} 
          onClick={()=>setIsOpen(oldIndex => index === isOpen ? 'nothing' : index)}>
          {isOpen === index && (
            <Popup project={proj.name} description={proj.description} />
          )}
        </ProjectContainer>
      ))}
    </Wrapper>
  );
}
```

The state stores the index of the current opened popup.

ProjectContainer onClick event check if the current index is the same as their and changes accordingly : to 'nothing' if they are currently opened, to their index if they are not.

The condition `{isOpen === index && (` is used to show only the current opened popup ie the current index.

This way you can toggle an individual project and not all of them.

Comment: In this case the condition should be ```isOpen === index```

Comment: Why in the useState should I put -1 value?

Comment: So none of them is toggled when the component is first rendered =) Or saying nonsense and it toggles the last one

Comment: After I use this solution, after page is loaded the popup is visible and it won't work

Comment: I forgot the ```isOpen === index``` maybe try with it

Comment: Ye, I've changed that and it's still doesn't solve the problem.
Now my popup won't display

Comment: Ok, I edited it the hard way, no more -1, just a good old 'nothing'

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin right now my code looks exactly like in your answet but now, after I click a component popup window won't display.

Comment: Ok one last thing and I'm out, I edited index to oldIndex, there was a problem with variable names.

Comment: Ok. This time It worked but I had to change: 
from: (oldIndex === isOpen ? 'nothing' : index))
to: (oldIndex === isOpen ? index : "nothing"))

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin could you explain me this code in few words?
I don't fully understand how does it works.

Comment: @TheRobertos After your penultimate message I was a bit confused and had to think a bit and found that one oldIndex has to be an index. Because your current implementation works only with 2 objects. (Edited answer, again..)

Comment: @TheRobertos Are you ok with my explanations ?

Comment: `oldIndex` is the previous state of `isOpen`, so it should be `setIsOpen((prevState) => (prevState === index ? "nothing" : index))`.

Comment: @JeanJacquesGourdin 
Yes. I understand it now. Thank you so so much! It’s an important lesson for me!